# How can I edit or customize the required characters of a username field?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm making a blog type website, and it's pretty much done but earlier today I realized a major flaw in it. **When creating creating a username (when registering or editing one's profile) it asks for certain characters, but it won't allow me to have spaces in my name.**

**For example** if I wanted my username to be "Winston Pichardo", it won't be possible because that will trigger the error that says "only letters and digits as @/./+/-/_  are allowed".

***So how can I edit these 'requirements' to allow spaces in the username?***

I'm using the default django forms and combining those with Crispy Forms to make it all work.

**these are some examples of my code:**

*forms.py*

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label= 'Correo Electrónico',
        required=True,
    )
    username = forms.CharField(
        label = 'Nombre de Usuario',
        required=True,
    )
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label = "Contraseña",
        required=True
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label = "Confirmar Contraseña",
        required=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label='Correo Electrónico',
        required=True
    )

    username = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        label='Nombre de Usuario'
    )


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(
        label = 'Foto de perfil'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

*register.html*

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Cree su cuenta</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Registrarse</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">
                ¿Ya tiene una cuenta? <a class="ml-2" href='{% url 'login' %}'>Inicie sesión</a>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>             
{% endblock content %}
```

*apps.py*

```
class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

***Please feel free to tell me if you guys need something else from my code.***

Comment: You need to create a custom validator for that purpose and override the existing one for `username` field. related: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/validators/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the method is you can update your Model's username filed and can add validator like :

```
username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, 
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(r'^[\w. @+-]+$', _('Enter a valid username.'), 'invalid')
        ])
```